# simulate light in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, simulator, light

I am making a light simulator where each beam of light is individually calculated.
I have a problem though:

When I make a beam of light shoot out that has a rgba color of 0 0 0 0.01 it draws a black beam of light instead of doing nothing.  I am wondering how to draw it by only making the background brighter.

[This is a img of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSFxy.jpg)

Currently light shoots out of a light source as a white beam then hits a ball which only red deflects off of it.  Then that beam shoots into a ball which only deflects blue light... BUT since the beam was red (and red and blue do not share rgb colors) I made it turn black.  But when that beam shoots of it draws black light over my white light as seen in the img.

I have tried to draw each of the rgb seperatly like so:

```
c.beginPath();
c.arc(x, y, size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
c.fillStyle = "rgba(" + red + ", 0, 0, 0.01)";
c.fill();
c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, " + green + ", 0, 0.01)";
c.fill();
c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, " + blue + ", 0.01)";
c.fill();
```

Here is a code snippet of what a currently have.  (And I know a few things don't work the way they should but let's focus on the light problem.)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = ctx.getContext("2d");

c.fillRect(0, 0, 1400, 600);

var particles = [];
var blocks = [];
var enhansers = [];
for (i=0;i<360*4;i++)
{
 particles.push( new Particle(300, 300, i/4, [255, 255, 255]) );
}

blocks.push( new Block(100, 300, 60, [0, 0, 255]) );
blocks.push( new Block(500, 300, 60, [255, 255, 0]) );


setTimeout('update()', 4000);

function Block(x, y, size, rgb)
{
 this.size = size;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.rgb = rgb;
 c.beginPath();
 c.arc(x, y, size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 c.setLineDash([5, 3]);
 c.strokeStyle = "green";
 c.stroke();
}
function Enhanser(x, y, size, en)
{
 this.size = size;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.en = en;
 c.beginPath();
 c.arc(x, y, size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 c.setLineDash([5, 3]);
 c.strokeStyle = "orange";
 c.stroke();
}
function Particle(x, y, deg, rgb)
{
 this.angle = deg;
 this.light = 0.06;
 this.size = 4;
 this.speed = 4;
 this.delight = 1.0001;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.rgb = rgb;
}

function update(n)
{
 for (i=0;i<particles.length;i++)
 {
  particles[i].light /= particles[i].delight;
  particles[i].x += Math.cos( particles[i].angle ) * particles[i].speed;
  particles[i].y += Math.sin( particles[i].angle ) * particles[i].speed;
  
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(particles[i].x, particles[i].y, particles[i].size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  c.fillStyle =
   "rgba(" + particles[i].rgb[0]
   + "," + particles[i].rgb[1]
   + "," + particles[i].rgb[2]
   + "," + particles[i].light + ")";
  c.fill();
  
  if (/*(particles[i].rgb[0] == 0 && particles[i].rgb[1] == 0 && particles[i].rgb[2] == 0) || */particles[i].light < 0.005 || particles[i].x > 1400 || particles[i].x < 0 || particles[i].y < 0 || particles[i].y > 600)
  {
   particles.splice(i, 1);
   i --;
  }
  else
  {
   for (j=0;j<blocks.length;j++)
   {
    if ( Dist(particles[i].x, particles[i].y, blocks[j].x, blocks[j].y) < particles[i].size + blocks[j].size )
    {
     particles[i].speed *= -1;
     
     particles[i].x += Math.cos( particles[i].angle ) * particles[i].speed;
     particles[i].y += Math.sin( particles[i].angle ) * particles[i].speed;
     
     if (particles[i].rgb[0] > 255 - blocks[j].rgb[0])
     {
      particles[i].rgb[0] = 255 - blocks[j].rgb[0];
     }
     if (particles[i].rgb[1] > 255 - blocks[j].rgb[1])
     {
      particles[i].rgb[1] = 255 - blocks[j].rgb[1];
     }
     if (particles[i].rgb[2] > 255 - blocks[j].rgb[2])
     {
      particles[i].rgb[2] = 255 - blocks[j].rgb[2];
     }
     break;
    }
   }
   for (j=0;j<enhansers.length;j++)
   {
    if ( Dist(particles[i].x, particles[i].y, enhansers[j].x, enhansers[j].y) < particles[i].size + enhansers[j].size )
    {
     particles[i].delight = (particles[i].delight-1)/(enhansers[j].en+1) + 1;
     
     break;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 if (particles.length > 0)
 {
  setTimeout('update()', 10);
 }
}
function Dist(x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
 return Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) );
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>

<title> Light </title>

<style>



</style>
</head>
<body>


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1400" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Light.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's really unclear what you are doing and what you want to do. Could you please create a [MCVE] s that we can focus on the problem? Because with what you gave, then yes, `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)` is a black with very little opacity, but still black, and yes `rgba(n, 0 , 0 , a) + rgba(0, n , 0 , a) + rgba(0, 0, n, a)` is not `rgba(n, n, n, a)`

Comment: @Kaiido I added my code now.